# How to check if string is valid python code (runtime error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there a possibility to check on Runtime errors? It is clear from a string that pri1nt is a function and it is not defined in this string.

```
import ast

def is_valid_python(code):
  try:
     ast.parse(code)
  except SyntaxError:
     return False
  return True

mycode = 'pri1nt("hello world")'

is_valid_python(mycode) # true

exec(mycode) # NameError: name 'pri1nt' is not defined
```

Comment: This wouldn't be a syntax error. `pr1nt` is a perfectly valid name in Python; the fact that it is not defined means there would be a NameError. But generally this kind of static analysis is hard to do in Python without actually executing the code.

Comment: If you don't know what the problem is there are many python programming softwares that automatically regognise mistakes and show the exact line and the type of error. Also in your script pri1nt is supposed to be print.

Comment: @Hoog No.. that's the entire premise of the question.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you can only know whether python code runs or not by actually running it. But with the `ast` module you can do some of the stuff that I imagine you try to achieve, e.g. check if names can resolve.

Comment: For example, I don't think there is a way to make sure that something like `my_dict['some_key']` will not produce a `KeyError` without a ridiculous amount of work. This is not something you want, right?

Comment: All the information is present in the string. It is computationally expensive validation to run a string.

Comment: "All the information is present in the string." No it's not. Does `from os import environ; print(environ['FOO'])` produce a key error? Nobody knows, unless you run the code.

Comment: I want to validate only the information in the string. It is clear that there is no method to validate `from os import environ; print(environ['FOO'])` other than run.

Comment: "It is clear that [...]" I doubt that, but hope you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `BaseException` instead of `SyntaxError`. This would check every type of python error, including `NameError`. Also, because `ast.parse` never raises any errors, you should use `exec` instead.

So it should be like this:

```
def is_valid_python(code):
  try:
     exec(code)
  except BaseException:
     return False
  Return True

mycode = 'pri1nt("hello world")'

is_valid_python(mycode) # false
```

Comment: Parsing code doesn't raise its errors. Executing `ast.parse('x = y')` doesn't raise a `NameError`, even though it obviously does once the code is actually run.

Comment: Well.. just `exec`ing the code runs into the same problems as the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this?

```
import subprocess

script_string = "prnt(\"Hello World!\")"    
proc = subprocess.Popen(["python"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
res = proc.communicate(bytes(script_string, "UTF-8"))
```

what it basically does is pipeing the string to a python interpreter. if no error, then the script_string is valid.

Edit: `res` will contain `(stdout_data, stderr_data)` (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)

Comment: This won't work for something like `while True: pass`, which runs with no errors.

Comment: `NameError: name 'true' is not defined` is my output

Comment: Sorry, typo on my part.

Comment: yeah, `string_script` gets executed. thats probably not intended.